# How to connect PC and Mac directly via Wi-fi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, osx-lion

I have 2 notebooks. One with Windows 7 another with Mac OS X Lion. How do I connect these notebooks via Wi-fi directly without a router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup an Ad-Hoc network, one system, join it from the other.

First system setup:

- OSX http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-an-ad-hoc-wireless-network.html
- Windows http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd296746.aspx