# How to connect a MacBook Air and a PC via wireless?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ad-hoc-network

I have a PC and a MacBook Air 2013 (with Mavericks installed). Both of them are able to connect to the internet via my wireless modem (DLINK DSL-2730U), however I want share some files and folders with my Mac and PC.

I have Googled a lot and found some answers such as the answer to [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/393444/how-to-connect-pc-and-mac-directly-via-wi-fi) and didn't understand the answer.

Comment: Hi the answer you quote above is correct and will work, if you don't want to set it up the way it is described, you could just use a USB stick to transfer the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can remember, you must enable SMB sharing or Windows sharing in Mac. In Windows, if you allow sharing with user account, you have to add your Mac's account to the allowed/trusted list. For more convenience, you can just allow access to everyone (disable asking for an account) if it is a home network. If at the Mac side you are asked for an account, use Guest. In Windows make a folder shared and let everyone access it if you don't want to mess with accounts. Make sure you allow modifications if you want also to be able to write or change files from Mac. Network must be set to work or home. In the Mac, browse for servers and you should see the shared resources. In worst case go directly at //PCname/resource  where PCname is the computer name and resource is the shared resource name.

Sorry I cannot guide you exactly, but I don't have a Mac. That's all I remember from setting up a friend's Mac. He had Lion, but I don't think Mavericks is too different.